# 95% confidence interval for p in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have to construct a 95% confidence interval using R, but I'm completely lost :( 
This is the assignment:

> In a random sample of 200 claims filed against and insurance company
>   writing collision insurance on cars, 84 exceeded \$1200. Construct a
>   95% confidence interval for the true proportion of claims filed
>   against this insurance company that exceed \$1200.

Please help me :(

Comment: Are you having a trouble understanding how to program this or how to calculate the confidence interval mathematically or both?  I'm afraid if it's just how to implement this in R, it's off topic and better suited for the Stack Overflow boards.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: No I know how to use R, but I don't understand how I can find the answer using R by inserting my values in to an "equation" saying fx. 'qnorm(37,100,5)'. 

Mathematically I would solve by using this equation (but that's not my problem): x/n -(Zaplha/2)sqrt((x/n(1-x/n))/n)<p<x/n+(Zapha/2)sqrt(x/n(1-x/n)/n).

Comment: If i had a set of data, I would copy them into R and use the function "t.test(arg)" and it would have given me the 95% confidence interval, but now that I'm only provided with the above mentioned data, I don't know which function(s) to use to find the 95% confidence interval :(

So I guess i would say I'm having trouble programming this.

Comment: Why would you use `t.test` when you're dealing with a *proportion*?

Comment: `prop.test( 84, 200 )`

Answer (score 2):

Well let's go on what you've given us, and what you've demonstrated that you understand.

You've told us that you know you want to solve:

$$
\frac{x}{n} \pm z_{\alpha/2} \sqrt{\frac{x/n \times(1-x/n)}{n}}
$$

So plugging in the relevant values into the equations which you've given us will give us the solution.

The only question remains is exactly what is $z_{\alpha/2}$, and what is its distribution?

Once you can solve that you can easily determine the confidence interval simply by entering the equation like you would in any other programming language:

```
x = ??
n = ??
z = ??
xn = x/n

zstat = z * (sqrt(xn*(1-xn))/sqrt(n))
lowerci = (xn - zstat)
upperci = (xn + zstat)
```

---

Other things that you can think about:

- What exactly is the distribution you are assuming the question?
- Is normality assumption required?
- Is there an exact test?
- Why would/wouldn't t-test function work out in this case?